# Log4j logs generating inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, log4j

I have configured log4j as a logger in my java code. Whenever i create a docker container,then the log path which is set as a environment variable will generate inside docker container instead of generating log file on a specified path.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That's how docker works. It will generate the logs in container itself since it's acting as an independent machine. What you can do is use volumes to mount the log directory to the host file system. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/
If you have a docker compose yml you can use


volumes:
      - ./logs:/home/logs

Comment: I want to generate the logs on a specified path of docker command.....but it is creating a same directory inside a docker container......I will post the command  docker run -e INTERNAL_LOG_PATH=/var/log/gRPC -p 50081:50081 -v /var/log/docker.log/:/var/log/gRPC/ -d service_name /opt/jboss/grpc/runServer.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount your **host** file system directory to you **docker container** and thats how you share data between host machine and container.
follow this link - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host